# Skyrim house murders?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Quite new to Skyrim so quick question:

I've noticed that when I kill an entire building/household full of people and get the *Bounty removed* message, the guards will still come after me regardless the moment I step out of the house.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You should only do that when you can kill all the guards to :D.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth noting that when you get the 'Bounty Removed' message, it is accompanied with a value of how much bounty was removed. If the bounty removed is lower than the bounty you gained from killing everybody then you will still have a bounty with that hold - which would explain why the guards still come after you.

Also keep in mind there are [some known 'issues' with the way Bounties work](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bounty_(Skyrim));

- Friendly fire on an ally such as Imperial Soldier or Guard raises bounty.
- Bounties can be accrued even if witnesses are not present. Sometimes chickens, dogs, and other wild animals can be witnesses to a crime as they are considered entities.
- Guards will sometimes attack criminals even if the crime was unseen and no bounty was placed. They will not give the option of yielding. Sometimes only a few guards will attack, while the rest go about their normal business.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Don't kill an entire building/household full of people.

Alternatively, it might be a bug - try this:

http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=19

But this is only for the pc.

Out of interest, was it the brothers in faeldun or whatever you wiped? I remember i broke into their house/business (you know the ones. The grumpy lumbercutter and his brother who warns you against stealing) once and mopped the floor with them. Got the "no bounty" message, and then was promptly smacked down by the guards when i walked outside.

No other crimes were committed there either! I just stone cold rolled in and killed the brothers.

oh wait, now i remember... i had lock picked my way into their house. and they were complaining that "i shouldn't be here" for a bit before i showed them some dragon diplomacy. that might have been it too.

Comment: man i hate those brothers. i'll restart the game soon just to cold kill em again. they might be in faeldon, of course!